# Can't remap ctrl or alt combinations to commands

Tags: vim, vimrc

In Vim, I am ttempting the following remaps:

```
nnoremap <A-1> :make<CR>
inoremap <A-1> <Esc>:make<CR>i
```

Basically, I want to remap alt+1 to :make. However, this remap fails and I can't see why.

The map

```
nnoremap q :make<CR>
```

works. Why is that? Isn't < A-1> the proper way to describe alt+1?

Edit: I am using terminal vim.

Answer (score 0):

`<A-1>` is a proper way to describe `<M-1>`, but I doubt that your terminal emulator sends it when you press Alt-1. Most probably it sends `<esc>1`, so you can map:

```
:nnoremap <esc>1 :make<CR>
:inoremap <esc>1 <C-o>:make<CR>
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. alt-1 does nothing.

Comment: @morphheus Well, show what your term sends when you press Alt-1 though: in Vim input mode: `<C-v><ALT-1>`.

Comment: nothing! I had tried that too. other commands (such as ctrl-c) show up, but no alt commands.

Comment: @morphheus Hmm... What terminal emulator do you use?

Comment: gnome terminal. (i'm running arch linux w/ gnome)

Comment: @morphheus So you have a problem with GNOME Terminal. I do not use it (neither recommend somebody to use it), but it seems that it intercepts Alt hotkeys for some awkward reason. See [that bugreport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/875070).

Comment: Since Vim saw nothing at all in insert mode when you pressed CTRL+V followed by your desired key combination, then with your current terminal settings Vim *cannot* map that key, because Vim never receives that key. You will need to use gvim, a different terminal, or find a way to get your terminal to send a mappable sequence.